# How to handle the "out of range" exception in C++ when implementing a nd-array

Tags: c++, arrays, numpy, range

I was trying to implementing a nd-array in C++ like numpy in python, but I do not know how to handle the problems(or exceptions?) like "indices out of range". Should I just use the assert to check the parameters at the beginning of the functions, or use try/catch/throw mechanisms?

BTW, if I use assert, how to print the error messages like "the input index is out of range" to users instead of just "assert at line 5 failed" assertions.

the macro I am using right now to check the index:

```
#define RANGE_CHECK(total, index) assert(total > index)
```

Comment: Note: `assert` is typically implemented as no-op on non-debug builds.

Comment: An answer to your 2nd question: Use `std::cerr` to flush your error messages to the console.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method used by the standard library is to throw [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range), from [functions named `at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), and to have undefined behaviour in [functions named `[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).

Comment: You meant operator[] indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Asserts are for things that never ever should happen and the only way to handle them is to terminate the program. Basically you never ever want to use them (although sometimes it's the only way).

So go with exceptions. The std lib already has a number of excpetions defined that you can throw for stuff like index out of range. Use them.

With exceptions the default will be to terminate the program, just like with assert. But unlike an assert the program can try/catch the exception and handle the error if they like. It's then their job to print a more meaningfull error message if they so desire.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is the world of **lazy** programmers; they normally tend to stay off exception handling as long as possible. As @Caleth mentioned earlier, following std conventions, one can provide a none-throwing `operator[]` as well as a throwing `at`. But boosters proposed a postponed exception-handling approach throughout either of the following:

1. std::optional:
   Return a `std::optional<T>` instead of  `T`:

   `std::optional<T*> arr::at(size_t)noexcept;`
2. Provide a none-throwing overload - alongside the throwing function - with an extra `std::error_condition` reference argument:

   `T* arr::at(size_t) throw(std::out_of_range);

   T* arr::at(size_t, std::error_condition &ec) noexcept;`
3. return a pair of value and std::error_condition:
   `std::pair<T*,std::error_condition> arr::at(size_t)noexcept;`